# Sharepoint 2013 Intranet and Extranet Topology - How?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, extranet, intranet

I am currently trying to decide on a Sharepoint Farm Topology.

Currently (in terms of our needs), I think a simple three tier topology will work.

i.e.

Web Front-End Server Application Server Database server

To start with our primary aim will be to use SharePoint as a Intranet. However, on our roadmap we would like to extend some elements of this - as an Extranet with some coustomers.

Should we go with an Extranet option in the future, so do we just (in simple terms) create a new web application in Sharepoint 2013 on the existing web front end, sort out a host header and SSL and a means to manage permissions.

Or could we create a new front-end server, which is only houses a new web application (the Extranet) - but still uses the same Application and Database server (as it will be potentially sharing the some of the same content databases)?

I am primarily a C# Web Developer - which is typically how I view most things. As I am learning - in the world of SharePoint nothing is simple!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following topologies for SP2013 and SP2010 respectively

5 Servers SP2013 Test and Productive Environment:

1x WFE Server
1x Application Server
1x Database Server
1x SharePoint App Server
1x Office Web App Server

In SP2013 the above mentione topolgy gives you the flexibility to manage the farm more precisely

---

3 Servers SP2010 Test and Productive Environment: :

1x WFE Server
1x Application Server
1x Database Server

---

P.S. The same configuration you should also have in Test Environment. i.e you should maintain test and productive environment inorder to maintain correct operating.

Comment: Also see this link just to get a broad idea. http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/how-choose-sharepoint-farm-design